# How to show app name while adding event to calendar?

Tags: android

I am new to android, i have two calendars in my device while adding events from my app to device prompt is showing calendar with respective package(com.android.calendar), google calendar (com.google.andriod.calendar).
But in S4 its showing perfectly as calendar whereas in Motorola tablet showing with package names. My requirement is to hide these package names in all device.

```
            if (!checkTheEvent()) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventTitleData);
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, bun_author);
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                            convertMilliseconds(start_date_time));
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                            convertMilliseconds(end_date_time));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
                    convertMilliseconds(end_date_time);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  AlertDialogUtil utils=new AlertDialogUtil(this,  (AlertResponse) this);
                    utils.showDilaog(R.drawable.calendar_alert, "The Calendar Application is missing on this device.", "Warning", true);
                }
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                // Android 2.2+
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://content://com.android.calendar/events/"
                        + String.valueOf(CustomCalendar.eventID.get(position))));
                intent.putExtra("beginTime",
                        convertMilliseconds(start_date_time));
                intent.putExtra("endTime", convertMilliseconds(end_date_time));

                // Android 2.1 and below.
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
            }
```

Comment: show some code..how you are adding these ?